# Why function doesn't display the value of parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a newbie and I'm helping a colleague to debug a code. The code below doesn't return the width and height values to the show_camera function. In console, the `show cam width` always display a `0`.

```
function show_camera($, width, height) {
    $('#snap').css('display', 'block');
    $('#camera-container').css('display', 'block');

    $('#avatar img').css('width', width);
    console.log("show cam width: " + width);

}
```

Below is how the function above is called.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    center_buttons($);

    $(document).on('click', '#cam-button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var video = document.getElementById('video');

        const vgaConstraints = {
                video: {
                    width: { min: 800, ideal: 800, max: 1280 },
                    height: { min: 450, ideal: 450, max: 720 }
                }
        };
        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(vgaConstraints).then(function(stream) {
                    localstream = stream;
                    FLAG = true;
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();
                    show_camera($, video.getBoundingClientRect().width, video.getBoundingClientRect().height);
                    console.log("width:" + video.getBoundingClientRect().width);
                    console.log("height:" + video.getBoundingClientRect().height);
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    //alert(AJAX_OBJ.perm_txt);
                    alert(err.name + ": " + err.message);
                    console.log(err.message);
                    hide_camera($);
                });
...
...
```

I could get `width: 280` from the above. But why not from the show_camera function.